# Can I code within latex?

Tags: coding

I want to make a slide show that displays different slides depending on input that I give it. Simple example: Given n, display 2n. Can Latex do this?

The idea is that the values in the slideshow will depend on how many people are in attendance, so I want to be able to change that number on the fly.

Comment: Change in the code and re-compile to obtain a different presentation with the appropriate number? Yes. On-the-fly as in "Javascript in the PDF using LaTeX"... yes. As of now, it's not all that clear what you want though.

Comment: But Javascript will depend on the cooperation of the PDF viewer, of course.

Comment: Thanks @Werner. To be more specific: suppose there are $n$ people in the audience, and I ask them how many handshakes will take place if every person shakes hands with every other person. Then I ask a bunch of other questions that all depend on that number $n$. I want to have slides with the answers ready to go and I just want to set the number $n$ somewhere in the code before I start the slide show. What I'm actually doing is a bit more involved, but the idea is the same: can I create formulas with variables in the tex code so I can give the variables exact values to fit the situation?

Comment: @Jack your question is very unclear as to _where_ you want to input the data, but assuming that you can run pdflatex again before the slideshow then yes that's what latex does all the time, Just code your slides  using `\n` and edit the first line to say `\newcommand\n{27}` once you know what the number is.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, that is a helpful first step. Now suppose I want a slide to display the value of n(n-1), using the 27 that I set as the \newcommand argument. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `\the\numexpr \n * (\n - 1)\relax` for example but there are latex packages to do far more extensive calculations, calculate trig functions etc. The language is turing complete so in principle it can do _any_ calculation.

Comment: Thank you again @DavidCarlisle. I found fp that seems to be working fine for what I need. What about if-then statements? For example, I want to display the numbers 1 through n on consecutive slides, and then go to the next frame. Can I set a counter, i, so that if i \leq 27 it displays ``i'' on the next slide and then increments i, else it goes to the next frame?

Comment: sorry this site can't handle help conversations in _comments_ there are multiple questions about if constructs tex primitives or the `ifthenelse` package or ...